# Q: How to sanitise XML files with xmlstarlet?

Tags: cmd, xmlstarlet

I've got several xml files to sanitise via the command line tool xmlstarlet (1.6.1).

**Sample 1**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Some license comment
   - with some link to http://example.com/foo/ -->

<OpenSearchDescription xmlns="http://a9.com/-/spec/opensearch/1.1/">
  <ShortName>Name Sample 1</ShortName>
  <Description>Description Sample 1</Description>
  <InputEncoding>UTF-8</InputEncoding>
  <Image height="16" width="16">data:...</Image>
  <Url type="text/html" method="get" template="https://examplesearch.com/" rel="searchform">
    <Param name="q" value="{searchTerms}"/>
    <MozParam name="m1" condition="purpose" value="abc"/>
    <MozParam name="m2" condition="purpose" value="cde"/>
  </Url>
</OpenSearchDescription>
```

**Sample 2**

```
<!-- Some license comment
   - with some link to http://example.com/foo/ -->

<SearchPlugin xmlns="http://www.mozilla.org/2006/browser/search/">
  <ShortName>Name Sample 2</ShortName>
  <Description>Description Sample 2</Description>
  <InputEncoding>UTF-8</InputEncoding>
  <Image width="16" height="16">data:...</Image>
  <Url type="application/x-suggestions+json" method="GET" template="https://www.examplesearch.com/search?client=firefox&amp;q={searchTerms}"/>
  <Url type="text/html" method="GET" template="https://examplesearch.com/search" rel="searchform">
    <Param name="q" value="{searchTerms}"/>
  </Url>
</SearchPlugin>
```

I try to clear the `Description` node first which works for **sample 2**:

```
xml ed -L -u "//_:SearchPlugin/_:Description" -v "" sample2.xml
```

The result is the node `<Description/>`, but the same logic does not work for **sample 1**:

```
xml ed -L -u "//_:OpenSearchDescription/_:Description" -v "" sample1.xml
```

I'd like to receive `<Description><Description/>` as results for both xml samples.

***Update:*** The previous part has been solved.

Secondly, in **sample 2** I'd like to remove `client=firefox&amp;` out of the second `Url` template value:

```
"https://www.examplesearch.com/search?client=firefox&amp;q={searchTerms}"
```

I've got no clue how to apply a regex/xslt operation on the value to achieve this. Any suggestions how this could be done?

Comment: I managed the `<Description></Description>` task with the command:
`xml ed -L -u "//_:Description/text()" -v ""` for both cases.

Comment: Does your comment mean that there is no longer a question to address?

Comment: No, I updated my original posting but someone restored the original version. I'm still looking for a solution for the second part, i.e. removing the `client=firefox&amp;` substring. I haven't got a viable approach for it yet.